# Assigning Arrow Key Functionality to Alt+[Key] in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to map the functionality of arrow keys to `Alt+J`, `Alt+I`, `Alt+;`, and `Alt+K` using AutoHotkey. The idea is to enable **cursor navigation within text without moving my hand from its resting position on the keyboard**.

I am currently using the following script to achieve this:

```
!j:: send {Left}
```

This script works to an extent. When I press `Alt+J`, it moves the cursor to the left, as expected. However, when I hold down `Alt+J` to move the cursor further to the left, it moves a little, but it also types `j` letters into the text.

I have tried several solutions suggested by OpenAI's ChatGPT-4 model, but none have resolved the issue.

Would appreciate any advice or solutions that could help me fix this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Works fine here. Try it first in a standalone script (Use only this code in the script and close all other scripts that may interfere).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is working, but If I hole on alt+j it should keep going left without typing j.
But what happens is that it moves to left, types j, moves, types and so on.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your keyboard (dirty?) or its driver.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the  keyboard hook by adding the [dollar prefix($)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar):

```
$!j::send {Left}
```